# String parsed date test in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to verify a method that contains date parsing implementation.

```
@Override
public void pasreDates(String startDate, String endDate) {
    LocalDateTime startDateTime = null;
    LocalDateTime endDateTime = null;
    // parsing date and times
    try {
        startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startDate, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(endDate, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        LOGGER.error(ERROR_PARSING_DATE_TIME, e);
    }
}
```

I just tried to test this using JUnit the date and times(both dates) and verify the log if an exception occurred. My test method looks like

```
@Test
public void should_log_an_error_if_given_date_string_is_in_invalid_format() {
    dealMapsUtil.storeDataToProductIdToDealDateMap(dummyProductId, dummyDeal, dummyStartDate, dummyEndDate);

    verify(logger, times(1)).error(ERROR_PARSING_DATE_TIME);
}
```

How I verify the date format and what are the other test cases that I can write for this method? I've went through few tutorials but dind't help.

Comment: Maybe you can compare your result string with a string that you know that is correct, i.e: `mydaDateResult.equals("12/02/2018");`

Comment: you verify `logger.error(String)` but your CUT calls `logger.error(String, Throwable)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Timothy Truckle correctly noticed, you don't verify what you invoke.
You invoke `logger.error(String, Throwable)` but you verify `logger.error(String)`. It can only fail.

Whatever, mocking and verifying `Logger` is generally not straight and it should be performed only as we don't have choice.

1) Actually you don't unit test `parseDates()`.  You test it in "integration" as you invoke a method that invokes it :

```
 dealMapsUtil.storeDataToProductIdToDealDateMap
```

Unit tests should focus on the tested behavior.
If this method can be invoked from multiple places, you should wonder if it would not be relevant to test it **first** in its own class and to "verify" that it is called in the tests of the caller classes.

2) `parseDates()` doesn't define a clear API for client classes as the single way to check if the parse failed are logs.
Logs and behavior results are distinct things and the first one should not replace the second one.
To make it more handly, you could return a `boolean` to indicate the result of the parsing or throw an exception in `parseDates()`.
In this way you could test this method very straightly.

Comment: thanks for the answers. As you mentioned I changed the test as follows,
`@Test
    public void should_log_an_error_if_given_date_string_is_in_invalid_format() {
        boolean result = dealMapsUtil.storeDataToProductIdToDealDateMap(dummyProductId, dummyDeal, dummyStartDate, dummyEndDate);
        verify(logger, times(1)).error(ERROR_PARSING_DATE_TIME, Exception.class);
        assertTrue(result);
    }
`
please guide me know if any correction on this

Comment: You are welcome. It is not exactly what I proposed but the idea is not bad. Note that as the parse fails i would expect rather false as return value. An you should not need any longer to mock the logger if you check the boolean value.